# I would Like to Use Flows to Ask user to select a Record type and Then Accordingly next screen appears to Create a Record of that record Type

Tags: flowscreen

[image]There is a Use Case where I need to give a Screen to the end user with options of Available Record Types (More than 1) , Depending on the option he selects the next screen with fields related to that record type should appear!!
Help me out!!
Below is the image for better understanding of the Question
[image]

Comment: What do you need help with? What isn't working based on the screenshot you sent? You can [edit] your question with details.

Comment: I am Unable to Crack the Logic for the Decision Box 
I am Putting the Resource as Record_type (Which is the Screen Picklist to choose a Record type) and Operator as Equals , value as Record Type Name !!!
It still doesnt work

Comment: Hi are you able to do this flow success fully. I am also in the situation I need to create a screen flow which displays record types and once the record type is selected display the only required fields to fill and once fields are field save the record.

Answer (score 1):

> In order to show the list of record types do the following -
>
> 1. Make sure the user running the flow has read access to the standard RecordType Object.
> 2. Query on the RecordType object with SObject Name as your desired Object and you will get a list of RecordType.
> 3. Store their Name field as a choice set and show it against a picklist on the first screen.
>
> On the basis of the selected record type, your decision will now
> handle which screen to show.
>
> This will take a little effort but your record type will always be
> dynamic.
> [image]

> Easy Way -
>
> Create a picklist choice set in the flow builder with the record type
> name and then add it on the first screen.
>
> Again, On the basis of the selected record type, your decision will
> now handle which screen to show.
>
> This is easy but the record type will be static.